# Convert list to bullet-points

Tags: r-markdown

If I have a list of characters: `list("bannana", "apple", "orange")`, I would like to get a R chunk with the output:

```
- bannana
- apple
- orange
```

Moreover, with a list with structure `list(fruits=list("bannana", "apple", "orange"), meat=list("beef", "chicken"))`, I would like to get:

```
- fruits
  - bannana
  - apple
  - orange
- meat:
  - beef
  - chicken
```

Is this possible? I could consider also a table as output, but I think that would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple list:

```r
l <- list("bannana", "apple", "orange")
cat(paste0("- ", l, collapse = "\n"))
```

- banana
- apple
- orange

For a 2-level list, maybe something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
list2markdown <- function(l) {
  enframe(l) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(items = paste0(
      "- ", 
      name, 
      paste0(
        "\n\t- ", 
        unlist(value), 
        collapse = ""))) %>% 
    pull(items) %>% 
    paste0(collapse = "\n") %>% 
    cat()
}

l <- list(fruits = list("bannana", "apple", "orange"), 
          meat = list("beef", "chicken"))

list2markdown(l)
```

- fruits

  - bannana
  - apple
  - orange
- meat

  - beef
  - chicken

Comment: Pretty awesome, I'll check this and once I can confirm it works for me, I'll mark it as answer. Thanks!